# App created with AIR 3.4 Won't Work in AIR 3.7

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flexbuilder

I recently overlaid AIR 3.7 into the Flex 4.9.1 SDK.  An iOS app I created works perfectly with 3.4 (which I created it with). Part of the app is to either take a picture or get it from the Camera Roll (and save a compressed version) However, in 3.7 the app hangs once the MediaEvent.Complete code is called (code Below) Any Ideas, do I need to add a loadercontext?

```
protected function onComplete(event:MediaEvent):void {


            //Busy Indicator

            bi = new UploadAlert(); //upload Alert is a component I created to display a Busy indicator
            bi.x = this.width/2 - 150;
            bi.y = this.height/2 - 150;

            //Get number of elements
            allElements = this.numElements;



            this.addElementAt(bi, allElements);





            var cameraUI:CameraUI = event.target as CameraUI;


            var mediaPromise:MediaPromise = event.data;

            var mpLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            mpLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);

            mpLoader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);


        }

        private function onMediaPromiseLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var mpLoaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
            mpLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);

            this.imageProblem.source = mpLoaderInfo.loader;






                var bitmapDataA:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mpLoaderInfo.width, mpLoaderInfo.height);
                bitmapDataA.draw(mpLoaderInfo.content,null,null,null,null,true);  



                var bitmapDataB:BitmapData = resizeimage(bitmapDataA, int(mpLoaderInfo.width / 4), int(mpLoaderInfo.height/ 4));  // function to shrink the image





                var c:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
                c.addBitmapData(bitmapDataB);

                var now:Date = new Date();
                var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("IMG" + now.seconds + now.minutes + ".jpg");                                    
                var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
                stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);                                         

                // Then had to redraw and encode as a jpeg before writing the file


                var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                bytes = bitmapDataB.encode(new Rectangle(0,0, int(mpLoaderInfo.width / 4) , int(mpLoaderInfo.height / 4)), new JPEGEncoderOptions(80), bytes);




                stream.writeBytes(bytes,0,bytes.bytesAvailable);
                stream.close(); 




            imagefile = f;
            deleteFlag = 1;

            this.removeElementAt(allElements);

            this.btnRotate.enabled = true;
            this.btnDelete.enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: IF the app is hanging; how do you know it is on this code?  have you stepped through in debug mode?  Which line of code is causing the problem?

Comment: Ok the debug session told me this: VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.display::JPEGEncoderOptions could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the problem was NOT with my code. It WAS in fact when I overlaid AIR 3.7, The files for air-config.xml, flex-config.xml, and airmobile-config.xml were still targeting too low of version of flash player.  It was 11.1 and swf version 14.

It should have been 11.5 and 18 respectively. Once I changed these files, it worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer and came back to post it.  +1 from me.  You should be able to mark this answer as "accepted"